# postfix check_policy_service with multiple action results

Tags: postfix

I have read everything I can find on the subject of creating a "graylist" script and the script is functioning mostly as I intended.

I have postfix calling the script using the check_policy_service option and the script functions just fine.

I read the section that many articles reference "man 5 access" and this doesn't seem to answer one question.

From what I can see using observation, no matter how many lines my script returns, only the very first action=???? row is accepted. All the others are ignored.

What I am trying to do is send a PREPEND and OK during the same pass. This doesn't seem possible but I cannot confirm or deny this through any sort of documentation or web search. I found a coupld that say it is possible but they really only say "read man 5 access" which says NOTHING about sending multiple actions.

I am running Ubuntu 17.04 server

If I send the action=PREPEND first, the action=OK is ignored. If I send them in the reverse order, the action=PREPEND is ignored.

Does anyone know, what my script needs to return to properly get postfix to accept both the OK and PREPEND in a single pass?

The closest thing I was able to find said I had to run the script twice by calling it twice from postfix. This doesn't sound like a good solution as it uses twice the effort.

Thank you in advance for any examples or documention you can point me at.